# Lazy loading : Angular 1.6.x version using Webpack

Tags: webpack, lazy-loading, code-splitting, angular1.6

We built angular application ,which has more module components. Because of more module components its taking time to load initially (its loading all components initially).

Presently i have done code splitting using **webpack(1.3.x version)**. It has 2 entry points , one is `index.js` which have all module components registered and second is `vendor.js` which have third party angular packages. But i need to do lazy loading in 3 spaces such as

1. Login
2. User space
3. Person space

My need is , at entry point only login component should load, after successful login want to load user space related components,later if i enter into person space then only my application should load person space related components.

`How can i achieve this using webpack lazy loading or code splitting`, any help recommanded.

Thank you.

Comment: What all specific aspects you have tried, or have found out to match your scenario

Comment: I'm not getting any idea to split index.js file for lazy loading as it is importing all components.